# Integrating RTK Query with Lightstreamer WebSocket in React

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query, lightstreamer

How should I properly use RTK Query with Lightstreamer WebSocket in a React application? Are there any specific steps or configurations I need to consider for a seamless integration?

Here is my sample code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { setConnectionStatus } from './lightstreamerSlice';
import { LightstreamerClient } from 'lightstreamer-client-web';

export const lightstreamerApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'lightstreamerApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://your-lightstreamer-server' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}), // Add at least one endpoint here, even if it's a dummy one
});

const lsClient = new LightstreamerClient('https://your-lightstreamer-server');

export const { useLazyQuery } = lightstreamerApi;
export const { reducer: lightstreamerApiReducer } = lightstreamerApi;

// WebSocket connection setup
export const setupWebSocket = (dispatch: any) => {
  // Set up a connection details
  const connectionDetails = {
    user: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
  };

  // Add connection details to the client
  lsClient.connectionDetails.setUser(connectionDetails.user);
  lsClient.connectionDetails.setPassword(connectionDetails.password);

  // Connection event listeners
  lsClient.addListener({
    onListenStart: () => {
      dispatch(setConnectionStatus(true));
    },
    onListenEnd: () => {
      dispatch(setConnectionStatus(false));
    },
  });

  // Connect to the Lightstreamer server
  lsClient.connect();
};

// Clean up the connection
export const cleanupWebSocket = () => {
  lsClient.disconnect();
};
```